# How to categorize records clearly in the backend of TYPO3 (6.2)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I used to have all my records in one page in the backend ("appointment data" in the picture below). That wasn't very user friendly because the backend users had a hard time finding the records they were looking for.
I want to make it easier for them by having different pages for different records.
In my extension-builder I created multiple entities that extend fe_users (in the example below: Workers, Students and Lawyers).
I want a page for each of these entitys like this:
[image]
I then changed the pids of the fe_users to be in the corresponding page.

Now nothing works anymore. :(

I can't even log in after changing the pages-container setting to *website users*:
[image]
Not to mention none of my appointments show up even though I tried changing the Record storage page of my extension to my *Data* folder recursively:
[image]
I'm aware that I'm probably just missing some basics here.
But I don't even know what to search for because there might be a completely different way to do this categorization thing I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can recognize your page-icons from your screenshots I think you have your user data in pages which are hidden.

Records from hidden pages are also hidden. Hidden records are not available in the FrontEnd (FE), so no user can log in with this data.

Try to enable the pages!

Comment: thanks you for this hint, I didn't know that before - it's still not working but I'll get there :)
I can log in by now after changing the fe_users storage_id to multiple ones with typoscript (even though they were in disabled pages) - if I get the rest working I might be able to answer my own question^^

Answer (score 1):

Changing the *Record Storage Page* to the folder recursively like I did was correct after all.

The problem there like Bernd said was that I had disabled my Record Pages.

For the frontend login I found out eventually that in my root template I had set the storagePid to the old one and I didn't know you can set it to multiple ones (comma separated) like it says [here](https://wiki.typo3.org/Felogin) in the description of storagePid.

The reason why it still didn't show up was because of an error in my query which I will ask in another question probably.